# Multi-line indentation using description

Tags: horizontal-alignment, description

I'm having trouble using `description`. I would like the separation between my label and my description to be the same distance for each item, and have each additional line also be properly indented to the same distance, like so:

[image: desired]

So far all I seem to be able to get is:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description} [leftmargin=*,labelindent=16pt]
\item [To:] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The same code produces itemized lists when description is changed to enumeration, which is not exactly the desired effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use table maybe is alternative way to accomplish the format.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=50pt,leftmargin=!]
\item [\textbf{To:}] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\item [\textbf{From:}] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description} [labelindent=16pt,style=multiline,leftmargin=1in]
\item [To:] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\item [From:] Defense Advisor
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `leftmargin` as you wish to change the separation.

Comment: What must be the relationship between `leftmargin`, `labelindent` and `labelwidth` to make this work? Especially, how did you arrive at those “magic” `1in` and `16pt`?